# Aws Glue Workflow triggering multiple times one job (incorrect behavior)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a big glue workflow (about 100 jobs / crawlers), and it was executing properly until last week. Since then, my first conditional trigger (ALL), is executing 20 time the same job.

I've configured the job it self, to just allow 1 parallel execution, but every time the workflow executes, it tries to launch 20 times (the same job).

Also configured the workflow, to allow a max concurrency of 1, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Since i started working with glue workflow, i've noticed that the tool it self is buggy, old and maybe deprecated ?

Any tips on how to fix this problem ?

Comment: If you are using Aws GLue Worflow, change the solution. The app is not maintained by aws and has some bugs. Step Functions worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too have faced similar problems. Even one is fixed, some other issue would occur lately. So my suggestion is to try using step functions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).